# TclXML- Installing TCLXML on Unix Server

Tags: xml, tcl

Am a new beginner using TCLXML. Can someone help me install TCLXML on Unix Server?
I need to use TCL Scripting to parse XML File. Please throw some light here.

Comment: http://tclxml.sourceforge.net/tclxml/3.2/README.html#installation

Comment: Can you help run the xml file on unix server?